# Method intrinsicContentSize() conflicts with getter from superclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

The following function in Swift 3 gives off a compiler error:

```
func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 55.0)
}
```

"Method 'intrinsicContentSize()' with Objective-C selector 'intrinsicContentSize' conflicts with getter for 'intrinsicContentSize' from superclass 'UIView' with the same Objective-C Selector"

How do I apply this function in Swift 3?

Comment: Your code would have been illegal in a different way if your code had been more "correct" and you had said `override` like you're supposed to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a property, not a method, so in Swift it's overridden using the property syntax rather than a getter method as it would be in Objective-C:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 55.0)
}
```